# Why is Binary Tree Data Structure better that Linear?

Tags: data-structures, binary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, binary-data

Why Binary Tree data structure considered as better than when compared to linear data structures? Please explain with a suitable diagram.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Who says that a binary tree is "special"? Define "special"?

Comment: I fixed it.give plus effort

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. _Why_ do you think it is special?

Comment: i dont know. This is the data structure paper question

Comment: Then consult your course materials for that answer. We don't know what your teacher wants to hear. It is special compared to what?

Comment: Compared to what other data structures? In one sense, *all* data structures are special when compared to others. Each one is unique, and used for different purposes. Lists, trees, dictionaries, heaps, etc. all are "special" in their own ways. You need to be more specific with your question.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: Start by reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree, and then give some thought to how that structure would be superior to a linear list for some applications.

Comment: thanks for reply all...I found answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

A binary tree is special because when you are searching it you repeatedly decide whether to follow the left branch or the right branch eliminating half of the tree each time (assuming the tree reasonably well is balanced).  In fact, this is what you do each time you add a node.

Take a look at http://www.computersciencebytes.com/array-variables/binary-trees/.